# AVG antivirus detecting my React Native Android App as Malware

Tags: android, react-native

AVG 2016 antivirus is flagged my React Native Android App as Malware. The App is built based on RN.

The was app build from source using:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html

The App doesn't require any special access. Uses AWS CDN to load images and all queries to our backend use TLS.

Comment: React Native it's a new framework, maybe AVG does not recognize the new libraries

Comment: Can this be related to LICENSING & IN-APP BILLING KEY?

Answer (score 2):

Until somebody finds the root of the issue, you can submit your APK file as a falsely detected sample: https://secure.avg.com/submit-sample

I had the same issue with my Android App (not using React Native). A few days after submitting, they removed the detection and I did not have any problems in later versions of my app.